# Attempted to read or write protected memory on MWSafeHandle

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, garbage-collection, finalizer

I'm getting an error back when running my C# program that interfaces with the MCR (using MATLAB R2015b). The error happens very infrequently and is difficult to reproduce. When it occurs, it states the following:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

And the stack trace for the error is:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. 
at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWSafeHandle.mclMxRefDestroyArray(IntPtr pMXArray) 
at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWSafeHandle.ReleaseHandle() 
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize() 
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize() 
Data of System.AccessViolationException: No entries.
```

I'm using MWArrays in my program, and the issue seems to be the finalizer tripping up on a MWSafeHandle. 
I never explicitly use the MWSafeHandle, however I try and call the Dispose() method on each of my MWArrays when I'm done using them (and I'm assuming this is correlated to the MWSafeHandle finalizer issue). 
Specifically invoking the Dispose() method doesn't really seem to be necessary (https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/57290a83-9e6e-4179-a1b8-9fb0344544ce.htm) but I want ot reduce the uncertainty and memory footprint of my program by disposing of the MWArrays myself.

Some additional observations I've made is that when I'm profiling my program using the .NET memory profiler, I'm seeing that the MWSafeHandle is marked as being garbage collected but not properly disposed. I viewed the disposed instances after running my program and specifically calling garbage collection using:

```
GC.Collect()

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() 

GC.Collect()
```

Does explicitly calling the Dispose() method on MWArrays lead to problems? If I forgot to explicitly dispose of the MWArrays somewhere could that also lead to issues?
Any help is appreciated, and if more information is needed, I'd be happy to provide it!

Additionally, I've received the following advice on the issue - but it didn't help:

Copying the "mclmcrrt711.dll" to the folder that contains your .NET application can lead to issues

Having mixed dependencies (some dependencies for the x64 platform and some for the x86 platform) can be problematic.

I've checked, and I don't have dependency issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems your `Dispose` calls are not liked by their `MWSafeHandle` implementation. Obviously, it shouldn't but... well. It would be interesting to see `MWSafeHandle` implemenation (i.e. via dnSpy).

Comment: @KonradKokosa I found a similar DLL [here](https://github.com/quantlabs/matlab_test_to_csharp/blob/master/TestInCSharpCon/TestInCSharpCon/bin/Debug/MWArray.dll). `MWSafeHandle` is `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` and overrides `ReleaseHandle` which calls `mclMxRefDestroyArray(IntPtr pMXArray)`. I don't see how this one can be called with the wrong `IntPtr`. Even if the OP's stacktrace indicates this is called by the finalizer, I don't see how it can be called given that `Dispose` has been called once and the handle is now `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: `protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
      if (MWMCR.MCRAppInitialized && IntPtr.Zero != this.handle)
      {
        MWSafeHandle.mxDestroyArray(this.handle);
        this.handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (this.unmanagedBytesAllocated_ > 0L)
          GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(this.unmanagedBytesAllocated_);
      }
      return true;
    }`

Comment: @Ethan can you upload `MWArray.dll` and give us the link?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I don't own the MWArray.dll implementation so I don't feel comfortable posting it. However, the implementation you referenced is basically identical to the implementation I'm using. Out of curiosity - do you have any commands/code you suggest I run against the .dll to uncover anything? Let me know - thanks again for the help!